# cropping raster using polygon not selecting all cells in terra package

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have a raster and I am trying to crop it using a polygon

This is my polygon:

[image]

My raster file contains the entire globe at 0.25 degree resolution so I cropped the raster using the polygon:

```
 library(terra)
 crop_raster <- terra::crop(temp_rast, county_ref)  
 plot(crop_raster)
 plot(county_ref, add = T)
```

[image]

This cropping looks odd since only 2 raster cells are selected. I was expecting something like below which I get using the `snap = "out"` argument.

```
crop_raster_snap <- terra::crop(temp_rast, county_ref, snap = "out") 
plot(crop_raster_snap)
plot(county_ref, add = T)
```

[image]

Why didn't the crop argument worked in the first instance? And what is the purpose of the 'snap' argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of `crop`, with SpatRaster argument `x`, and SpatExtent (or the extent of another spatial object) argument `y`; that argument "snap" is

> One of "near", "in", or "out". Used to align y to the geometry of x

`y` needs to be aligned to the geometry of `x` because you cannot crop partial rows or columns. You can only crop entire rows or columns. So you have three options, go inwards (smaller area), outwards (larger area) or to the border that is nearest.

Comment: this took me an embarrassing long time to figure out and (I think) is a change for folks used to raster::crop/mask defaults.  IMO, 'out' should be the default here...
Many thanks for year of dedication to these packages